# Gconf, Dconf, Gsettings and the relationship between them

Tags: gconf, dconf, gsettings

I'm trying to understand how Gconf, Dconf and Gsettings works and what the relationship is between them.

All I know is:

- **Gconf** - XML based database (backend system). The older one.
- **Dconf** - BLOB based database (backend system). The newer one.
- **Gsettings** - CLI tool to edit settings. Looks like it works only with Dconf (although I saw somewhere that it might work with Gconf).

I know that for Gconf there is a GUI - Gconf-editor, and for Dconf - Dconf-editor.

So:

1. Which backend system is more often used - Dconf or Gconf?
2. Gsettings works with both of them? And why doesn't it show all Dconf schemas?
3. Where does Dconf save its data?

Comment: I would be particularly interested in which settings are handled by which tool (dconf or gsettings) and why there are differences?

Comment: I also want to know the important details that no-one ever seems to mention: what kind of resourcing do they need? Do they both run a service for instance?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

GConf is obsolete. It is the older GNOME 2.x configuration API and system, and has been replaced by DConf/GSettings in newer versions. However, some applications still use it.

GSettings is a GLib implementation of DConf, which stores its data in a binary database.

The `gsettings` command line tool is simply a tool to access or modify settings via the GSettings API, in the same way that the older `gconftool` command line tool is for GConf.

Comment: Is GSettings works with GConf also?

Comment: No, GSettings is an implementation of the DConf spec. The command line tool doesn't work with gconf. There are however, some compatibility layers currently in use on Ubuntu, where changing a setting in gsettings or gconf, will result in the change being propagated to the other. This isn't common though, and not something to rely on.

Comment: another thing,i saw somewhere that GSettings works with configuration files. is there something about it?
and why does GSettings doesn't show the same schemas as DConf-editor?

Comment: GSettings doesn't work with configuration files. You could theoretically write a back-end for GSettings that uses configuration files, and configure it to use that, though. As for different schemas, I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: The interesting part to know would be which settings are managed by which tool? The keys which are present when using dconf or dconf-editor are different from those accessible with gsettings, for example there is a key /com/canonical/unity/always-show-menus accessible via dconf but there is no equivalent key accessible via gsettings in Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: @Johsm I presume you are confusing gsettings with gconf here, because gsettings IS built on dconf, so anything visible in dconf-editor can be changed via CLI with gsesttings.

Comment: OK, maybe I am confusing things here but what made me ask is this: if I run "dconf list  /com/canonical/unity/ | grep menus | grep always" I get as output "always-show-menus" but when I run "gsettings list-recursively  | grep canonical.unity | grep always" I get nothing. In other words, the key com.canonical.unity.always-show-menus is visible in dconf but not in gsettings. 
I am doing this on Unity 15.04 64 bit on a Lenovo w550s running Unity.

Comment: Because the schema is `com.canonical.Unity`, not `com.canonical.unity`.

Comment: @dobey: thanks! I completely missed that! But now i do not understand why it works with lowercase in dconf and only with uppercase in gsettings?

Comment: @Johsm One is a path, and the other is the schema. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @dobey: thank you for helping with this. What I am really after is though: how does the mapping between the key I have to use in dconf and the key I have to use with gsettings work? If I know one, is there an algorithmic way to find the other? In my concrete case I was given /com/canonical/unity/always-show-menus -- now how would I find the appropriate key for gsettings? If both use the same underlying data, should there not be a logical mapping? Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Read the schema file.

Comment: `gsettings list-schemas --print-paths` shows the correspondence, grepping for `[A-Z]` chars gives many examples of non-1:1 e.g. `org.freedesktop.Tracker3.FTS /org/freedesktop/tracker/fts/` or `ca.desrt.dconf-editor.Settings /ca/desrt/dconf-editor/`

Answer (score 69):

**Dconf** is a data store designed for storing configuration. It is the replacement for **Gconf**, which was used for the same purpose. Eventually, no programs should depend on Gconf any more.

**Gsettings** is a development library used to read and write to a configuration store backend. On Linux, it uses Dconf, but on Windows, it uses the registry, and on OS X, it uses a native data store. (The `gsettings` command on the CLI uses this library.)

Application developers and end-users are recommended to use Gsettings, not Dconf directly.

**See also:**

- [What are the differences between gconf and dconf?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34490/what-are-the-differences-between-gconf-and-dconf)
- [Can I use dconf-editor to modify Gconf settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122039/dconf-editor-and-gconf-editor)
- [GSettingsMigration on gnome.org](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/GnomeGoals/GSettingsMigration)

Comment: `gsettings` is a CLI tool though, like OP mentions. I think they want to know whether they should use that, or `dconf` (or `gconf`), basically.

Comment: @Victor I'm not sure I understand your comment. Like I said, application developers and end-users are recommended to use Gsettings, not dconf or gconf.

Comment: OP is specifically asking about "Gsettings - CLI tool to edit settings." That's the context. Not about the library.

Comment: @Victor I've edited the answer post to clarify that `gsettings` the CLI command uses Gsettings the library. Both application developers and end-users are recommended to use Gsettings (either as a library, or as a command on the CLI).

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring GConf here because it's obsolete.  TLDR: use `gsettings`.

## `dconf` is ignorant of schemas, so is blind to defaults

from `man dconf` (1):

> The dconf program can perform various operations on a dconf database, such as reading or writing individual values or entire directories. This tool operates on dconf directly, without using gsettings schema information.
> Therefore, it cannot perform type and consistency checks on values. The gsettings(1) utility is an alternative if such checks are needed.

I don't care that much about "type and consistency checks".
In practice, I see a more important difference — `dconf` only sees settings that I explicitly set.  Example of untouched settings:

```shellsession
> gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.interface | grep scaling
org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0
org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor uint32 0

> gsettings list-schemas --print-paths | grep org.gnome.desktop.interface
org.gnome.desktop.interface /org/gnome/desktop/interface/

> dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/interface/ | grep scaling
> dconf list /org/gnome/desktop/interface/ | grep scaling
> dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor
> dconf read -d /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor
>
```

Here `dconf read -d` claims it reads default values, but in practice does nothing for me?

I can still write it (blindly), even if to same 1.0 value as default and then dconf sees it:

```shellsession
> dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor 1.0
> dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/interface/ | grep scaling-factor
text-scaling-factor=1.0
> dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor
1.0
> dconf read -d /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor
>
```

Moreover, I can store any key I make up!  So it functions like a dumb **hash table** of exlicitly set values, and `reset` just deletes the entry:

```shellsession
> dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/foo 123
> dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/interface/ | grep foo
foo=123
> dconf reset /org/gnome/desktop/interface/foo
> dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/interface/ | grep foo
>
```

## `gsettings` uses schema data

Well, that makes sense.  I used `locate --regexp org.gnome.desktop.interface` and got a couple xml files (maybe not *the* right one), and the schema files do contain the default:

```xml
      <key name="text-scaling-factor" type="d">
        <range min="0.5" max="3.0"/>
        <default>1.0</default>
        <summary>Text scaling factor</summary>
        <description>
          Factor used to enlarge or reduce text display, without c>
        </description>
      </key>
```

So `gsettings` combines the actually set values with defaults.

That's why instead of single path it takes two arguments eg. `gsettings read SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY` — because it starts from the schema, maps it to dconf path (see `gsettings list-schemas --print-paths` but takes optional PATH for relocatable schemas), and then overlays the modified values from dconf.

It can also dump some schema info:

```shellsession
> gsettings describe org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
Factor used to enlarge or reduce text display, without changing font size.
```

but somewhat disappointingly, I don't see any way to just read the default (if a value is set), nor distinguish whether a settings is left at default or explicitly set to same value.

## `dconf-editor` also uses schema data

Despite its name, dconf-editor does show both modified and default settings, including which are default and which are explicitly set:

[image: screenshot from dconf-editor /org/gnome/desktop/interface/]

and is fully aware of schema info:

[image: screenshot from dconf-editor /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor]

Comment: Same here also my dconf doesn't show the schema/key for "org.gnome.desktop.default-applications" only if I list it by gsettings...