# which files does gconf-editor edit?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gconf

I want to change my gnome-terminal hotkey settings. I came across `gconf-editor` which enables me to customize exactly the things I need. However I need to know in which file these changes are made.

The gconf-path is `apps/gnome-terminal/keybindings/`
I found the file `~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/keybindigs`. But there are only two hotkeys listet.

Where are the rest of these settings stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `gconf-editor` man page

> GConf-Editor  is  a  tool  used  for  editing  the  GConf configuration
>      database.  It might be useful when the proper configuration utility for
>      some software **provides no way** of changing some option.

and

> This tool allows you to  directly  edit  your  configuration  database.
>      **This  is  not  the recommended way of setting desktop preferences.  Use
>
>      this tool at your own risk.**

Also look at the answers in [Gconf, Dconf, Gsettings and the relationship between them](https://askubuntu.com/q/249887/248158) for an overview on `gconf`, `dconf`, and `gsettings`.

To find which files are modified (edited) when you make your changes, you can use the `find` command.

```
find ~/ -mmin -5 -type f
```

will find all files in your home modified in the last five minutes. You can reduce the time `find` takes by excluding certain folders:

```
find ~/ ! -path "*mozilla*" ! -path "*cache*" -mmin -5 -type f
```

Will exclude `~/.mozilla` and `~/.cache` from being searched.

To give an example, I used `gsettings` to modify whether `FileChooser` shows hidden files and folders:

```
$ gsettings get org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden
false
$ gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden true
$ gsettings get org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden
true
$
```

I then ran `find` and saw that `~/.config/dconf/user` was modified. That file is a binary:

```
$ file user
user: data
$
```

In other words, you can't open it and see what's inside as you would open a text file or even a xml file.

I don't have `gconf-editor` or `dconf-editor` installed but you can use the same `find` command to find which file has been modified when you make your modifications and then use `file` to figure out whether you can see what that file contains (without using a hex editor).