# Could someone please explain to me the difference between gconf, gconf-2 and gconf-editor?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, gconf

I am really curios to learn about these 3 since I don't really understand how they work. I read somewhere that gconf-editor is basically the graphical representation of gconf however what is gconf-2 for?

Also, before I installed gconf-editor, I pressed Alt-F2 and tried to open gconf but it wouldn't open. What happens in the system if you click on gconf or gconf-2 as opposed to gconf editor?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

- GConf is a configuration database system for storing application
  preferences. It supports default or mandatory settings set by the
  administrator, and changes to the database are instantly applied to all
  running applications.
- [gconf2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/trusty/gconf2) (not gconf-2) is a binary package (I guess that 2 was meant to be used first for GNOME2 and was not change for GNOME3)
- GConf-Editor is a tool used for editing the GConf configuration database.

Note that `gconf` is now obsolete and has been replaced in recent releases by `dconf`.

Visit  [Gconf, Dconf, Gsettings and the relationship between them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249887/gconf-dconf-gsettings-and-the-relationship-between-them) for further details.

Comment: Also worthy to note that currently dconf is the succesor of gconf and that gconf is being fased out. So if it is not in gconf or does not work as expected also check dconf.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Good idea, I've updated my answer and added a link to a relevant post.