# How to edit gnome settings in config file(.xmll or other)

Tags: gnome, network-manager, vpn, notification

I enable connection notification with following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-connected-notifications false
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications false
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-vpn-notifications false
```

Is there conf to edit above settings? i hope see all settings and change them.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a practical or a theoretical question, but http://askubuntu.com/questions/249887/gconf-dconf-gsettings-and-the-relationship-between-them and http://askubuntu.com/questions/416556/shouldnt-dconf-editor-and-gsettings-access-the-same-database no more xml files.

Answer (score 2):

You can undo your settings with changing `false` to `true`:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-connected-notifications true
$ gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications true
$ gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-vpn-notifications true
```

Or you can reset the value of keys to default with `reset` option:

```
$ gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet disable-connected-notifications
$ gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications
$ gsettings reset org.gnome.nm-applet disable-vpn-notifications
```

> I hope see all settings and change them

Here it is you can list all of them by using this command:

```
$ gsettings list-schemas
```

Or if you want to get list all schemas with all keys and values, use the following command:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively
```

And for listing all the keys from a specific schemas, use `gsettings list-keys <SCHEMA-PATH>`

```
$ gsettings list-keys org.gnome.nm-applet
stamp
disable-disconnected-notifications
disable-vpn-notifications
disable-connected-notifications
suppress-wireless-networks-available
show-applet
disable-wifi-create
```

And listing their schemas-path and value:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.nm-applet
```

See [`man gsettings`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gsettings-tool.html) for more info.