# How can I toggle selected pulseeffects equalizer profile from command line?

Tags: command-line, sound, pulseaudio, 19.10, equalizer

I have `pulseeffects` installed and running. I have created a few equalizer profiles.

How can I toggle (enable/disable) selected profile using command line options.

I know I can just click on the profile but I would like to bind that to some global key to toggle it when needed. How can I do that?

I know I can load selected preset by using (where `v2` is a profile name):

```
   $ pulseeffects -l v2
```

But how can I disable (unload) this profile ?

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if you have 3 profiles like V1, V2 & V3 and you would like to select profile V1, you can run the below command

```
gsettings set com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects last-used-preset 'V1'
```

If you dont want this, you can use below command

```
gsettings reset com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects last-used-preset
```

[image: screenshot]

you can create a script with below content and call it with a shortcut you wish.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

key="com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects last-used-preset"
current=$(gsettings get "$key")

if [ "$current" == "'V1'" ]; then
  gsettings reset "$key"
else
  gsettings set "$key" "V1"
fi
```

[image: screenshot]

Courtesy by @MichalPrzbylowicz for toggling on and off

```
dconf write /com/github/wwmm/pulseeffects/sinkinputs/equalizer/state true
dconf write /com/github/wwmm/pulseeffects/sinkinputs/equalizer/state false
```

Comment: Yes, this selects given profile but does not enable/disable it afterwards... Is it possible to also activate/deactivate the profile ?

Comment: I mean turn on (process sounds by the equalizer preset) and turn off (do not process sounds).

Comment: I have added a screenshot. Please check. So I have like two things. Loading/Unloading a preset (You have already covered that) and turning it on/off - currently I can only do that in the GUI...

Comment: You can turn on and turn off using these commands: `dconf write /com/github/wwmm/pulseeffects/sinkinputs/equalizer/state true
dconf write /com/github/wwmm/pulseeffects/sinkinputs/equalizer/state false` . Please add them to your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: [End-users are recommended to use gsettings](https://askubuntu.com/a/249924/349837), not dconf directly: `gsettings get com.github.wwmm.pulseeffects.sinkinputs.equalizer state`