# How to run Compiz on Ubuntu Bionic Beaver?

Tags: 18.04, compiz, zooming

I'm not pretty sure what is the problem. But I already installed the Compiz Manager Settings (I want to be able to do zoom for creating tutorials) on my Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver) but no matter if I check the box for enabling the effect and configure the hotkeys no one effect is working.

**EDIT 1.**
I follow the answer of KYAA7 but I don't know how to use Dconf in order to Compiz to work.  I installed dConf editor as in the link provided by him. But it looks a bit different from the shown there. Here a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see there is no Compiz folder or something like that, also is not in the folder apps. What I suppose to do with this software for using Compiz and their zoom feature?

Comment: I am not sure, but do not think the default gnome desktop uses Compiz settings, might have to install unity if you want compiz.

Comment: and... is this recommended? I mean is there any conflict having unity and gnome?

Comment: Find unity works very well with gnome, but to just have compiz might not be worth it.  K7AAY has an answer below if you like gnome better than unity.

Comment: Well,  I maybe will try the answer of K7AAY. I also think that installing so many things just for use a zoom feature is not worth it.

Comment: Understand, maybe google gnome desktop zoom.  Might find something easy to do instead of installing stuff.  Gnome should have something like that.

Comment: Yes, There is the option of Zoom in Accesibility. But it's not the kind of thing I need for a tutotial. Thank you any way. I'm going to end this search by a while.

Answer (score 1):

[Compiz](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/arm64/compiz-gnome/1:0.9.13.1+18.04.20180302-0ubuntu1) needs the GNOME3 Shell extension [put-windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/). Then, you can install Compiz with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback`. Compiz settings are adjusted with [dconf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249887/gconf-dconf-gsettings-and-the-relationship-between-them) which is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it).

Comment: I did what you said til the dconf part. How can I use dconf for using Compiz? I'm an average user, just wan to use the Zoom of Compiz.

Comment: The thing is I'm still unable to make Compiz (through the CompizConfig Settings Manager) works and I don't understand dconf.

Comment: OK, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: Thank you I just edited my question in the sight of this new information. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP's edit: if you have got to the point where compiz works, you will find the keys you want under `/org/compiz` in dconf-editor. You can also look specifically for the zoom keys with the search function.

If you want a compiz-specific program for editing those keys, try `ccsm`: install it with
`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.