# Why do gsettings and dconf return different values?

Tags: 18.04, unity, compiz, dconf, gsettings

According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/249924/135465), it seems like `gsettings` uses `dconf` as a backend. I would therefore expect the following commands to output the same result:

```
$ gsettings get org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins
['core', 'composite', 'opengl', 'compiztoolbox', 'decor', 'vpswitch', 'snap', 'mousepoll', 'resize', 'place', 'move', 'wall', 'grid', 'regex', 'imgpng', 'session', 'gnomecompat', 'animation', 'fade', 'workarounds', 'scale', 'expo', 'ezoom', 'switcher']

$ dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/active-plugins 
['core', 'composite', 'opengl', 'place', 'put', 'regex', 'resize', 'session', 'snap', 'vpswitch', 'wall', 'animation', 'commands', 'compiztoolbox', 'copytex', 'fade', 'grid', 'imgpng', 'mousepoll', 'move', 'scale', 'unitymtgrabhandles', 'workarounds', 'expo', 'unityshell']
```

but as you can see, they do not. Am I missing something, or is this a bug? (Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity)

---

**Note 1:** from the manpage of gsettings:

> Note that gsettings needs a D-Bus session bus connection to write changes to the dconf database.

How can I check that this is the case on my computer?

**Note 2:** I remember seeing something about a gir1.2 package being uninstalled during a `apt autoremove` command at some point, but I cannot remember which one. Could this be related? Which `gir1.2` packages do I *need* to have if I am using Unity?

Comment: seems both are different schemas/keys u r using..

Comment: can you chexk with other simple schemas/values?

Comment: @PRATAP I would be happy to; what would you like me to check?

Comment: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picturi-uri` and its equivalent for dconf

Comment: @PRATAP They are different: 
`$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'

$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri
'file:///home/<username>/Pictures/Wallpapers/abstract01.jpg'`

Comment: yes.. some thing mysterious.. Ok is that output from adim account or standard account?

Comment: Admin account, should I try with a standard account?

Comment: no, its fine with Admin Account. So whats the real value from above two outputs. .png or abstract01.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107515/discussion-between-jonathan-h-and-pratap).