# Ubuntu system settings and command line

Tags: system-settings

I am running on Ubuntu 22.04 desktop and I want to be able to configure the system settings from the command line. A tool like the `gnome-control-center` is not applicable as it is GUI based. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I am now using Kubuntu. You need to expore gsettings. See: `man gsettings` & `gsettings list-schemas` and : https://askubuntu.com/questions/249887/gconf-dconf-gsettings-and-the-relationship-between-them

Comment: It appears that there is no schema for gsettings to cover the system settings.

Comment: What specific settings are you looking for?

Comment: Basically, all of them but specifically settings in Accessibility, Appearance, Screen Display. I am writing a program that will completely automate the customization of a Ubuntu instllation and thus need access to all the settings.

Comment: Last time I did a new install to another system, I copied /home/fred/.config which had most of my Kubuntu settings. Generally you just need to restore all of /home as the hidden folders are all the settings for everything.